# Return NULL when using template in C++

Tags: c++, exception, null

If I have an interface as below:

```
template <typename V, typename K>
V get(K key);  // Return the value of the key
```

Does the specification "return NULL when the key is not found" make sense? Is there anyway to handle the case when the key is not found except throwing an exception?

Also is throwing an exception the best way here to handle non-existing key?

Comment: Well if you can use the iterator method and return an iterator to the element.  If the element does not exist then return a sentinel iterator.

Comment: What if `V` is not a pointer?

Comment: If `V` is a pointer type you can return `NULL`, otherwise not.

Comment: Can you give a simple code example about this approach? Thank you! @NathanOliver

Comment: That is a case for boost::optional (which might become a std::optional)

Comment: I'll mention the one approach that wasn't mentioned, for completeness. And that is to use an output parameter + some sort of status code. But boost::optional is the superior method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot assume that `V` is a pointer. If `V` is `int`, for example, you cannot `return` the `nullptr` as it is no valid value for an `int`. And if `V` is a pointer type, think whether the `nullptr` would be a valid value for it to be inserted into your map. If so, how could the caller distinguish the `nullptr` that is `return`ed to mean “not found” from the “actual” `nullptr`?

If you are okay `return`ing a pointer to the item in the map, rather than a copy, consider this signature.

```
template <typename V, typename K>
V * get(K key);
```

Use `const V *` if you'd rather not have the caller modify the object in the map.

Alternatively, you could use an `optional<T>`. You can find an implementation in [*Boost*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) as well as as [an experimental extension to the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional).

Of course, you can also `throw` an exception to indicate that the key is not present in your map. However, this would only be considered good style by most coding standards if your clients had a reasonable way to know ahead of time whether the key is present or not. Exceptions should be used to signal abnormal, erroneous conditions. The fact that a key is not present in a map is unlikely to qualify for this, unless in your situation, the set of keys can be assumed to be known.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm just wondering is throwing an exception the best way to handle a non-existing key here?

Comment: @ZigZagZebra You can do it, but it probably won't be the “best way”. Please see the updated answer.